# Ubuntu Localization

Tags: language-support, internationalization, translation, localization

We are a language translation company and a strong believer in Ubuntu as we use it internally for almost everything.

Some of our clients have asked us for software recommendations (OS in particular) and we have told them we can provide them localized versions of Ubuntu and they are very excited. We would like to take the initiative to perform the localization on our own and share with the community down the road.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point us toward the direction for localization the Ubuntu UI. We are not sure about which languages but we would certainly like to complement what the community has done.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2):

For translating Ubuntu, you have to go here: https://translations.launchpad.net/
Instructions you can find here: https://help.launchpad.net/Translations